# PHP and MySQL: How to update MySQL Table using dropdown?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
<form method="post">
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td><select>
  <option value="volvo">Value 1</option>
  <option value="saab">Value 2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Value 3</option>
  <option value="audi">Value 4</option>
</select></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
</form>
```

I want to update my database with values on that table using PHP and MySQL query.
I know i need something like this, but how do i get values from dropdown list and input?

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable SET fields=<values> AND morefields=<inputvalues>
WHERE fields=<dropdownvalue>");
```

Comment: I'll try to answer as best I can, but you really need more detail in this question. It doesn't show me you've done any effort on your own to make this happen.

Comment: add a form element surrounding your table so you can submit it to your PHP!

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem with the question Zarazthuztra -.-

You have there html table and sql query i just need to know how to get the values....

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1) Use a standard HTML form

First, ensure you have a form enclosing your select input with action="yourphpscript.php" and method="POST"

Then, ensure the inputs you intend to access have NAME attributes. If they don't have name attributes, then the $_POST superglobal will not be populated with them. It'll be as if they don't exist.

```
<select name="auto_make">
  <option value="volvo">Value 1</option>
  <option value="saab">Value 2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Value 3</option>
  <option value="audi">Value 4</option>
</select>
<td><input name="some_field" type="text"/></td>
<td><input name="another_field" type="text"/></td>
<td><input name="and_another_field" type="text"/></td>
```

Then, ensure you have a button inside the form of type "submit" so you can actually do something with it.

Inside yoursphpscript.php you will do the following to get the value, given your select above:

```
$carMake = $_POST['make'];//your select
$someField = $_POST['some_field'];//your fir
$anotherField = $_POST['another_field'];
$andAnotherField = $_POST['and_another_field'];
```

2) Use AJAX

I'll give this example if you can show me you can do my first :)

Comment: The values in the variables I've given above are your starting point. Now it's time to make the effort to load them in and write the appropriate PHP and SQL

Comment: So in my query I will have something like this?
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable SET fields=$_POST['some_field'] AND morefields=$_POST['and_another_field']
WHERE fields=$_POST['auto_make']");